# Trying to copy files with a number sequence In cmd prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

hard drive  is dying, trying to save all my pictures and having to manually copy one by one in dos. The names are just numbered jpgs. Ie: 001 010 305 ect. Is there a way to make it copy them in order? I would just copy the whole folder but when it hits a corrupted file the drive dies and I have to re plug in. So if I could choose the starting point  and increment  up that would be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: you sure you are using ms-dos? isn't it rather windows' cmd?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?